Fixed the text passing above the navigation bar
when I scroll, the caption text passes above the navigation bar and crashes, even though it should pass below the navigation bar, how do I fix it
Well, like the picture here, what I marked in red is the description text which, when scrolling, actually passes above the navigation bar
so how to fix it, I tried setting it in CSS but I always failed because I was still a beginner in this problem

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

You can add CSS z-index to the navigation bar
example
if navigation bar use class

.navigation{
z-index:1000;
}

if navigation bar use ID

#navigation{
z-index:1000;
}

